# img tag in php code

Tags: php, image

How can I use img tag in php code?:

This is the code I have so far:

```
$message = $message."...<br /><a href=\"".$mybb->settings['bburl']."/".$announcement['threadlink']."\">".$lang->messagemore."</a>";
```

And I wish to use an image instead of  `".$lang->messagemore."`  but I don't know how to use img tag in php :|
I have tried googling but I only find some tag info from html but not php code.

```
<img src="/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif" alt="" />
```

But I wish to use that in php so I could use your help.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr

Replace: `$lang->messagemore`

With: `<img src="/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif" alt="" />`

---

When you replace your PHP variable with the `img` tag, the HTML must still remain within the quotes of the PHP string, and thus the actual quotes for your `img` tag must be escaped, just as you've done for your `a` tag.  You may also opt to use single quotes, to avoid having to escape.  This should result any one of the following equivalent code snippets (I've added whitespace for readability):

**Double quotes (with escaping):**

```
$message = $message . "...<br />
<a href=\"" . $mybb->settings['bburl'] . "/" . $announcement['threadlink'] . "\">
    <img src=\"/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif\" alt=\"\" />
</a>";
```

**Single quotes for HTML attributes:**

```
$message = $message . "...<br />
<a href='" . $mybb->settings['bburl'] . "/" . $announcement['threadlink'] . "'>
    <img src='/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif' alt='' />
</a>";
```

**Single quotes for PHP string:**

```
$message = $message . '...<br />
<a href="' . $mybb->settings['bburl'] . '/' . $announcement['threadlink'] . '">
    <img src="/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif" alt="" />
</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the HTML code ( in your case , the `<img>` tag ) in PHP , just like you did for `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
$message = $message."...<br /><a href=\"".$mybb->settings['bburl']."/".$announcement['threadlink']."\"><img src='/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif' alt='' /></a>";
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to add somthing like this:      <img src='.$mybb->settings['bburl']."/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif alt='' />       and its have problem :D

Comment: @user1973003 something like what?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$message = $message."...<br /><a href=\"".$mybb->settings['bburl']."/".$announcement['threadlink']."\">".'<img src="/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif" alt="" />'."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$message = $message."...<br /><a href=\"".$mybb->settings['bburl']."/".$announcement['threadlink']."\"><img src=\"/res/gif/bullet_info_sq.gif\" alt=\"\" /></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like that:

```
$message = $message."...<br /><a href=\"".$mybb->settings['bburl']."/".$announcement['threadlink']."\">"."<img src='".$aImageURL."' alt="" /></a>";
```

Simply replace de img src with a PHP variable. ($aImageURL will be the URI of the image)

Take a look at the quotes (I put simply quotes in the src attribute, you can do that)

Answer (score 0):

So simple, do not create mess with double quotes " PHP optimally used single quotes '. Use standard html within string!

```
echo ' <img src="php.gif" /> ';
```